# Why was my edit rejected then the same thing approved

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4907773) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873889/why-does-underscore-use-root-instead-of-this), which apparently was rejected.
However, an [identical edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23873889/2) was then made.

Why was mine rejected?

Comment: Looking at [his page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday?tab=activity) it seems that he revised rather than declined your edit. Its interesting that all of the edits that I can immediately see are "revised" rather than "accepted" maybe someone else can weigh in?

Comment: Looks like a race condition: the other editor had started working on the post just before you suggested your edit. When that happens, this sort of rejection follows.

Comment: @secretformula I wonder if he has something against giving <2k users  the +2.

Comment: @Scimonster: the other editor did not review your edit. They probably even weren't aware that there was one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the suggested edit that you showed:

- The Community♦ user rejected your edit, not an actual human.
- Nobody actually reviewed the edit.

Therefore, after you suggested the edit, but before three reviewers could approve it, a user who has over 2000 reputation suggested a similar edit coincidentally.  Therefore, that user was able to override your edit.

Your edit being rejected had nothing to do with the actual validity of the edit.